# Listview Subitem Images

Tags: delphi, listview

Am I missing something obvious here, I cannot find a way to assign an ImageIndex to a Subitem of a TListView.

I have the Listview set in vsReportMode with 2 columns, I can easily assign an ImageIndex to the first column Items, something like:

```
ListView1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 0;
ListView1.Items[1].ImageIndex := 1;
ListView1.Items[2].ImageIndex := 2;
```

I thought I could assign an ImageIndex to it's SubItems, something like this (which obviously does not work because the property does not seem to exist with SubItems)

```
ListView1.Items[0].SubItems[0].ImageIndex := 0;
ListView1.Items[1].SubItems[0].ImageIndex := 1;
ListView1.Items[2].SubItems[0].ImageIndex := 2;
```

Am I confusing myself again or is there no such property for SubItem Images?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `SubItemImages` instead:

```
var
  LI: TListItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  for i := 0 to 1 do
    with ListView1.Columns.Add do
      Caption := 'Column ' + IntToStr(i);

  for i := 0 to ImageList1.Count - 1 do
  begin
    LI := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LI.Caption := Format('Item %d', [i]);
    LI.ImageIndex := i;
    LI.SubItems.Add(Format('SubItem %d', [i]));
    LI.SubItemImages[0] := i; // SubItems[ColumnIndex] := ImageIndex;
  end;
end;
```

This results in

[image: ListView with SubItems and Images]

Comment: great thanks Ken, I don't how I overlooked SubItemImages, probably because I was pretty sure such a property would have been in SubItems[x].

Comment: That's what I would have expected as well, until your question prompted me to look into it. :)

Comment: What if i dont want image in the first column? If i want image only to subitems, i have to assign -1 to imageindex of the first column:

li.ImageIndex := -1;
li.SubItemImages[0] := 1;

The image then wont be shown in the first column, but the text in first column will get an offset with the size of the image.

Comment: @tdiop: You can custom-draw the first column if the default behavior doesn't work for you.